# Proof for convergence in distribution implying convergence in probability for constants

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

I'm trying to understand this [proof](https://www.probabilitycourse.com/chapter7/7_2_5_convergence_in_probability.php) (also in the image below) that proves if $X_{n}$ converges to some constant $c$ in distribution that this implies it converges in probability too. Specifically, my questions about the proof are:

1. How are they getting $\lim_{n \to \infty} F_{X_{n}}(c+\frac{\epsilon}{2}) = 1$?
2. Why do they state the conclusion at the end in this way? They're basically saying that knowing $lim_{n \to \infty}P(|X_{n} - c| \geq \epsilon) \geq 0$ allow you to conclude that $lim_{n \to \infty}P(|X_{n} - c| \geq \epsilon) = 0$ but the real reason we can conclude this is because of the whole body of the proof above, right?

[image]

Comment: using the same tutorial, encountered the same problem, came to the same question, Cheers!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If a sequence of random variables $X_n$ converges to $X$ in distribution, then the distribution functions $F_{X_n}(x)$ converge to $F_X(x)$ at all points of continuity of $F_X$.

In this case $X=c$, so $F_X(x)=0$ if $x<c$ and $F_X(x)=1$ if $x\geq c$. $F_X$ is continuous everywhere except at $x=c$, hence
$$ \lim_{n\to\infty}F_{X_n}\Big(c+\frac{\varepsilon}{2}\Big)=F_X\Big(c+\frac{\varepsilon}{2}\Big)=1 $$
as claimed.

For the second part, the argument has shown that the limit $\leq 0$, and the point the book is making (somewhat clumsily) is that the limit is of course non-negative, so these two facts imply that the limit is zero.

Comment: why do they divide by 2 instead of just saying $F_{X_{n}}(c+\epsilon)$

Comment: I meant to say: why do they divide by 2 instead of just saying $F_{X_{n}}(c+\epsilon) = 1$? Isn't this an equivalent statement, and then there wouldn't be the need to do the last few steps?

Comment: The issue is $\mathbb{P}(X_n\geq c+\varepsilon)=1-\mathbb{P}(X_n<c+\varepsilon)$, which is not necessarily equal to $1-F_{X_n}(c+\varepsilon)$.

Comment: Hmm, why is it not necessarily equal? Because we have $1 - P(X_{n} < c + \epsilon)$ instead of $1 - P(X_{n} \leq c + \epsilon)$? In general, why are we dividing $\epsilon$ by 2?

Comment: Yes, the = sign is the important part. After all, $\mathbb{P}(X_n=c+\varepsilon)$ could be non-zero. Dividing by 2 is just a convenient way to choose a slightly smaller point.

Comment: The clumsiness can be fixed if we cite the Squeeze Theorem.

Answer (score 0):

$\lim_{n\to \infty}P(|X_n−c|\ge \epsilon )\ge 0$ means that probability cannot be negative. And since $\lim_{n\to \infty} P(|X_n−c|\ge \epsilon )\le 0$ thus, $\lim_{n\to \infty} P(|X_n−c|\ge \epsilon )=0$.

Comment: hmm probability is always nonnegative right?

Comment: Yes, probability is always nonnegative. Maybe in Physics or other disciplines. But  I've never seen a negative probability.

Comment: so the deduction form the first line is confusing to me. We can just state directly that the probability is nonnegative right. Also, where does the second line comes from?

Comment: The first line comes from “axioms of probability" that is the probability of any event must be nonnegative. The second line comes from the proof shared by the user that is limn→∞P(|Xn−c|≥ϵ) ≤ limn→∞P(|Xn>c+ϵ/2) = 0.