# $X_n\to \textrm{Exp}(5)$ and $Y_n\to 10$ in distribution. To what does $E[X_n Y_n]$ converge?

Tags: probability, expected-value

I am solving the following problem.

> $X_n\to \textrm{Exp}(5)$ and $Y_n\to 10$ both in distribution. To what
> does $E[X_n Y_n]$ converge?

**My attempt:**

From [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proofs_of_convergence_of_random_variables),  I know that $(X_n, Y_n)\to (X, 10)$ in distribution, and also that $X_n Y_n \to 10X$ by combining the fact that “convergence to a constant in distribution implies convergence in probability” and Slutsky. However, I believe convergence in distribution does not say anything about the convergence of mean. So I do not know how to proceed.

Comment: one thing to note here is that you have something a liittle stronger, namely convergence in probability: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1716298/proof-for-convergence-in-distribution-implying-convergence-in-probability-for-co

Comment: @SamaelManasseh Yes, so by using that fact and Slutsky we can prove that $X_nY_n$ converges to $10X$ in distribution. But again I’m back to convergence in distribution.(which was what I’m trying to say in the question).

Comment: You know that $Y_n X_n \xrightarrow[]{d} 10 X $, take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_random_variables#Properties

Comment: @jDAQ I am not sure how that helps because the identity function $f(x)=x$ is not bounded.

Comment: Does it need to converge? Let $Y_n = 10 + Z_n$ where $Z_n$ is some classic counterexample where $Z_n\to_p0$ but $E(Z_n)\to \infty$ (e.g. let it be an independent sequence that is $n^2$ with probability $1/n$, else $0$).

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Although the problem seems to assume that it converges(and the professor said that it converges to 2), that was my suspect too. Thank you for providing some related counterexample.

Comment: You can say absolutely nothing about $EX_nY_n$. You are misquoting Wikipedia. Are you assuming INDEPENDENCE?

Comment: @geetha290krm are you talking about me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't necessarily need to converge, and can converge to anything you like. Let $Y_n = 10 + Z_n$ where $Z_n$ is independent of $X_n,X$ and is some classic counterexample where $Z_n\to_p0$ but $E(Z_n)$ converges to something nonzero, or goes to infinity (e.g. let it be an independent sequence that is $n^2$ with probability $1/n).$